# AS no importa ninguna libreria, ni siquiera AppCompat

Tags: android, android-studio

Formatee el PC y despues de instalar Android Studio y cargar proyectos que ya estaban en este mismo PC me aparecen de la siguiente manera y no logro dar con  la solución.

[image: Error Android Studio]

Cosas que he hecho tratando de solucionar:
- Clean Project
- Rebuild Project
- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Cambie de ruta el sdk ya que al créalo en la ruta user/appdata mi usuario tiene un espacio y daba error
- Ya tengo Java instalado en el pc

Dejo mi gradle por si puede ayudar en la solucion

[image: gradle1/2]

[image: gradle2/2]

Comment: Hola Leonardo, en el caso de código o configuración es mejor agregar como texto esta información. Con respecto a tu problema, ¿al cambiar la ruta correcta del SDK sincronizaste tu proyecto con los archivos gradle?

Comment: Hola Jorge gracias por la recomendación. Sincronizarlos, como ?

Comment: cuando realizas cambios en algún archivo gradle se muestra un mensaje en la parte superior derecha "Sync Now". Por cierto actualizaste previo a esto tu Android Studio?

Comment: Ha si lo sincronice de esta manera... El Android Studio lo instale desde cero ya que formatee mi pc por problemas con la tarjeta grafica.